# Search multiple files in subfolders and print only numerical values

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a question on in-line operation to search multiple files in sub-folders with TWO patterns, and print only numerical values.

Example:

Current directory: `$HOME/work/A/` (where to run script)

Subfolders containing data: `$HOME/work/A/trial1, trial2, trial3..`

Input (each data file):  eg. `trial1/trial1.out`

```
[text]
..
cutoff = 100
..
[text] 
..
! total energy= -23.4387 Ry
..
```

Need output: `/A/totalenergy.txt`

```
100   -23.4387
110   -23.2523
120   -24.0134
...
```

What I initially planned, is to use 'grep' to search each file and match pattern 'cutoff =' and '! ' to find the two desired lines, and print out only the cutoff number and energy number.

However, up to this point, what I am able to do is only search for 1 pattern, '! total energy' (more important), and use `grep | tr | cut > file` to get only the energy out.

```
grep -e "\!" */*.out | tr -s ' ' | cut -f5 -d' ' >totalenergy.txt
```

basically, I grep for '!', search all subfolders for *.out, trim multiple spaces, and retain only the numerical field

The line that contains '! total energy' after using grep looks like this

```
60/C.scf_60.out:!    total energy              =     -22.78085574 Ry
```

So, if I can somehow get the first number out from this line, plus what I have, I can also achieve my goal:

```
60  -22.78085574
```

I am trying to do this with one line command.

Thanks!

Comment: `egrep 'pat1|pat2' file` might give you some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: thanks. Is egrep unique to gnu?

Comment: no, `egrep` goes back to 1990s Unix systems (at least) ;-) . if you're using a `gnu` based system, you can do `grep -E 'pat1|pat2' file` (I'm pretty sure). the `[Ee]` in both cases refers to 'E'xtended regular expression support. And the `'pat1|pat2'` is one of a zillon forms for extended reg expersions. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much shellter! As both you and jaba10 suggested, two commands are needed to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -rn -e 's/cutoff[ =]+([0-9]+)/\1/p' -e 's/.*total energy[= ]+([0-9.-]+).*/\1:/p' */*.out | tr '\n:' ' \n'
```

---

### Explanation:

```
sed -rn -e <cmd1> -e <cmd2> */*.out
```

I've used `sed` instead of `grep`  because I fell into the necessity of using a flag (I choose `:`) to separate every register (*cutoff* *total_energy*).

#### sed options

```
-r # short form of --regexp-extended
```

Needed to match with the sintax I've used. Specially `([0-9.-]+)` -> I didn't need to escape the brackets, and I could filter `.-` without problems.

```
-n # short option of --quiet or --silent
```

It disables printing of patterns unless we explicitly ask to do so (with the flag `p`)

```
-e # short of --expression
```

Useful to combining multiple commands

#### pattern and replacement

```
cutoff[ =]+([0-9]+)/\1
.*total energy[= ]+([0-9.-]+).*/\1:
```

I'm just *saving* the value I need in `\1`.

Notice that I appended a `:` character after the value matched for *total energy*. As I said, it is to help me to separate registers with `tr`.

#### sed flag

```
's/../../p'
```

I've used `p` to print the patterns due to I'had disabled the printing with `-n`. It's needed to discard all the lines with no matches.

---

```
tr '\n:' ' \n'
```

Due to `sed` output each value in a different line, I used a flag (`:`) to know where to write a newline (`\n`).

#### characters replacement

[`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) is translating characters from SET1 (`'\n:'`) to the ones in SET2 (`' \n'`). The translation is taken replacing each character in  SET1 with each character in same position in SET2:

```
# \n  ->  " " (space)
# :   ->  \n
```

*Note: You'd maybe like to pipe once more (`| tr -s ' '`) to clean the output*

---

#### Another method to format the output

A more rigorous way to print the result is to `sed` again so the output is exactly as you want:

```
sed -rn -e 's/cutoff[ =]+([0-9]+)/\1/p' -e 's/.*total energy[= ]+([0-9.-]+).*/\1:/p' */*.out | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -r "s/([^:]+):[ ]*/\1\n/g"
```

Notice that util the first `|` the command is exactly the same as the one above.

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

It just replaces the newlines with spaces.

```
sed -r "s/([^:]+):[ ]*/\1\n/g"
```

It *saves* the string until `:` and prints it followed by a newline

Comment: I've just added a way to do it `sed`'ing again. I hope it helps you.